# EXC_BAD_ACCESS: Issues using std::array

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, stdarray

I am trying to use boost library's odeint with `std::vector` or `std::array`. I have no issues with compilation in either case, however, I have runtime issues regarding write to unknown address in the case of `std::array`. Given below is a MWE.

I have defined two classes: `ODE1`, and `ODE2` with `std::vector`, and `std::array` respectively in the header file `ode.hpp`.

```
#ifndef ODE_HPP_
#define ODE_HPP_

// c++ standard library headers
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace ode {
constexpr size_t n_variables = 1e4;
}  // namespace ode

class ODE1 {
 public:
  ODE1(const double o) : V_(ode::n_variables, o) {}  // explicit constructor

  std::vector<double>& GetVoltage() { return V_; }

  void operator()(const std::vector<double>& Y, std::vector<double>& dYdt,
                  const double /* time */) {
    using namespace ode;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < n_variables; n++) dYdt[n] = Y[n];
  }

 private:
  std::vector<double> V_{};
};

class ODE2 {
  using Array = std::array<double, ode::n_variables>;

 public:
  // constructors
  ODE2(const double o) { V_.fill(o); }  // explicit constructor

  Array& GetVoltage() { return V_; }

  void operator()(const Array& Y, Array& dYdt, const double /* time */) {
    using namespace ode;
    for (size_t n = 0; n < n_variables; n++) dYdt[n] = Y[n];
  }

 private:
  Array V_{};
};
#endif  //   ODE_HPP_
```

And the main function is defined in the file `ode.cpp'

```
// related header
#include "ode.hpp"

// other library headers
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

int main() {
  constexpr double abs_err = 1.0e-10;
  constexpr double rel_err = 1.0e-8;
  constexpr double sim_duration = 20.0;              // ms
  constexpr double t_start = 0;                      // ms
  constexpr double t_stop = t_start + sim_duration;  // ms
  constexpr double dt = 5e-3;                        // ms
  {
    std::cout << "ODE1\n";
    using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
    using error_stepper_type = runge_kutta_dopri5<std::vector<double>>;

    ODE1 o(-60.0);
    integrate_adaptive(make_controlled<error_stepper_type>(abs_err, rel_err), o,
                       o.GetVoltage(), t_start, t_stop, dt);
  }
  {
    std::cout << "ODE2\n";
    using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;
    using error_stepper_type =
        runge_kutta_dopri5<std::array<double, ode::n_variables>>;

    ODE2 o(-60.0);
    integrate_adaptive(make_controlled<error_stepper_type>(abs_err, rel_err), o,
                       o.GetVoltage(), t_start, t_stop, dt);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using the clang compiler on macOS Big Sur (11.5.2) as follows
`c++ -O0 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++17 ode.cpp -o ode`

As I mentioned above, I do not run into issues with compilation. When I run the executable, I have the following issues

```
ODE1
ODE2
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==30573==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffee6a1e3f8 (pc 0x00010896439e bp 0x7ffee6d18610 sp 0x7ffee6a1e400 T0)
    #0 0x10896439e in unsigned long boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_adaptive<boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_runge_kutta<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_step_adjuster<double, double>, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_error_stepper_fsal_tag>, ODE2, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::null_observer>(boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_runge_kutta<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_step_adjuster<double, double>, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_error_stepper_fsal_tag>, ODE2, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>&, double, double, double, boost::numeric::odeint::null_observer) integrate_adaptive.hpp:40
    #1 0x10894335e in unsigned long boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_adaptive<boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_runge_kutta<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_step_adjuster<double, double>, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_error_stepper_fsal_tag>, ODE2, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double>(boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_runge_kutta<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_step_adjuster<double, double>, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_error_stepper_fsal_tag>, ODE2, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>&, double, double, double) integrate_adaptive.hpp:83
    #2 0x10894262c in main ode.cpp:30
    #3 0x7fff203d0f3c in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15f3c)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow integrate_adaptive.hpp:40 in unsigned long boost::numeric::odeint::integrate_adaptive<boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_runge_kutta<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_error_checker<double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_algebra, boost::numeric::odeint::default_operations>, boost::numeric::odeint::default_step_adjuster<double, double>, boost::numeric::odeint::initially_resizer, boost::numeric::odeint::explicit_error_stepper_fsal_tag>, ODE2, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::null_observer>(boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_runge_kutta<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, std::__1::array<double, 10000ul>, double, boost::numeric::odeint::array_a
==30573==ABORTING
zsh: abort      ./ode
```

Strange enough, I do not have issues when I change the parameter, `n_variables`, in the header from 10000 to 1000.

Further, I used `lldb` to debug the issue and it seems to be `stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3fbc58)`

I am quite not sure what the issue here is! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASAN increases the amount of stack memory a program needs, and your program already needs a lot. Increase the stack size limit:

```
$ ulimit -s 81920
$ ./ode
ODE1
ODE2
$
```

Comment: thank you. Would this still work when different compiler flags are used? For example, replacing all the flags with only one, `-O3`.

Comment: @bhache It works for me but I have no idea if it will work on your system. Required stack memory directly depends on `n_variables`. How much it needs exactly, and how much is too much, varies from system to system.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that makes sense. On a different note, would `std::vector` be preferred over `std::array` when `n_variables` is huge? As I understand, `std::vector` is heap allocated where as `std::array` is stack.

Comment: @bhache yes, it seems `std::vector` would also solve the issue.